# Moving a rectangle around a "track" with curved edges

Tags: java, android, animation, path

I'm curious if someone can point me to a good tutorial on how to animate a "car" around a racetrack (assuming an overhead view).  Specifically I have a path that is the track (it's basically a rectangle with curved corners).  My specific area of confusion is how to calculate the rotation on the car as it moves through the curves if I were to advance it by N distance, as well as how to get the exact X,Y of any given point on the path.

So... assuming the entire path is J with start point S and end point E, I need to be able to place at at any intermediary point on the path and have be able to calculate what it's rotation should be, given where it is on the path, and what the X,Y screen coordinates are for that specific Path point.

I'd like to pre-empt the obvious "what have you tried" questions because I'm not at all clear on what the correct approach to this problem is, so, I have tried nothing other than articulating the specifics of the problem, in the hopes that I can be pointed at a good source of information on what that solution ought to be.

I'm doing this in Android, but I don't need an Android (or even Java) specific solution, just the principal.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The angle of rotation at any point in the curve is simply sin(x) or cos(x) (depending on your starting orientation). Basically, ignore the fact that you have rectangular sides and picture the four corners as a circle. Compute where you are on that circle and the rotation follows. If you're on a side and not a circle, it's really as if you're at one of the axes for a long time, but you can solve that as desired. It's really just a matter of figuring out how far into the circle (based on either x or y) one is, including the other value (x or y) specifying quadrant and using trig.

Comment: thanks... I understand what you're saying (and actually got that far before I posted), my problem is that since it's *not a circle and the curves at the corners aren't circle based (I don't know the geometric word for it, but they're more like sections of an oval, which aren't identical) and since the entire shape is one long path, I was assuming that since the path is a vector there's some straight forward way to say that if my car is at distance N from start it must (based on what that particular point represents) be rotated a specific way and occupy some specific X,Y on the screen.